# VB Script Regex returns unwanted match

Tags: regex, vbscript

From the strings below, I want only the first and third to be matched (not the second). That is only strings consisting of any repeating alphabet. e.g. aaa, aa, aaaaa, bb, cccc, ddd, zzzzzz etc

```
aa 
aa.ahab 
aaa
```

I am using the Regular expression below and it is returning an unwanted extra match (the second value above)

```
regexp.Pattern = "\b([a-zA-Z])\1+\b"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to match your requirement across the entire string, you should be using `^` and `$` anchors:

```
regexp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z])\1+$"
```

See in the demo link below that only the first and third input are matched.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Had missed out on the beginning and end markers (^,$)